# Why do files have modification dates after a git reset --hard ? Is this normal?

Tags: git

I'm on the `master` branch.

I made some changes by mistake.

I save those changes (I `cp` the files to be outside of this git repository)

I `git reset --hard HEAD`

Now I see:

```
...
-rw-rw-r--  1 durrantm  1415 Sep 24 10:32 regular_pair_filter_spec.rb
-rw-rw-r--  1 durrantm   474 Sep 24 10:32 ranking_spec.rb
drwxrwxr-x 10 durrantm  4096 Sep 24 10:32 ../
-rw-rw-r--  1 durrantm  7242 Sep 25 08:58 student_spreadsheet_spec.rb
-rw-rw-r--  1 durrantm  5400 Sep 25 08:58 iep_service_spreadsheet_spec.rb
-rw-rw-r--  1 durrantm 52487 Sep 25 08:58 schedule_spec.rb
drwxrwxr-x  2 durrantm  4096 Sep 25 08:58 ./
```

The files seem ok (changes are gone) but they have update stamps of today.
Is this ok/normal?

Comment: One of the git quirks I hate... If it's version control, then why reverting the version makes the file look as if it's the version of today?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git's [FAQ](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#Why_isn.27t_Git_preserving_modification_time_on_files.3F) has an explanation for this.

> Git sets the current time as the timestamp on every file it modifies,
>   but only those. The other files are left untouched, which means build
>   tools will be able to depend on modification time and rebuild
>   properly. If build rules change, that can cause a failure anyway, but
>   that is a far less common problem than accidentally not rebuilding.